# Nvidia card for a laptop can't be detected

Tags: drivers, nvidia

My VGN-SZ32CP laptop uses a NVIDIA GeForce Go 7400 GPU,but it seems that ubuntu does not detect it,like this:

```
dragon@dragon-VGN-SZ32CP-B:~$ lspci |grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML 
Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
```

But only the cheap Intel card.Is there anybody who has the solution for it?

Comment: Is it activated in your bios?

Comment: @Private unfortunatly, the bios on the Sony laptops do not have much to configure, except the boot order!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Is this an Optimus-enabled laptop or does it have "simple" switchable graphics? Do you need a button or software in Windows to switch between graphics? I think this is one of the pre-Optimus Sony-specific implementations of switchable graphics. Do you have a function key to switch? Please provide the additional information in your question by editing it.

Comment: It looks like you are having a NVIDIA Optimus graphics solution. Take a look at the bumblebee project:
http://bumblebee-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you go to System Settings>Software and Updates>Additional Drivers

[image: Screenshot]

and select a different driver, this may help

If you can not see any drivers for NVIDIA here, go to the software centre and search for NVIDIA X.org 173 or just NVIDIA X.org and install one of these.

Make sure you tick the Optional Add-ons so that you get to edit your settings then run the first part again to see if there is a later version you can try.

Comment: If `lspci` does not list the graphics card, then Ubuntu won't offer this driver, most likely - it's not detected at PCI-level.

Comment: hmmm. maybe not, I'll have a think...

Comment: @gertvdijk I have added a possible solution.

Comment: Hi,SimplySimon.I tried your way and it didn't work.I went to the place you went to,but there was nothing there.This laptop card had worked fine when I was using Ubuntu 10.10(the kernel 2.6),but when I switched to the 13.04(the kernel 3),it didn't work.I used other linux as well,but all the linux with kernels higher than 3.0 couldn't work.Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new at Linux and Ubuntu (just 2 months), and have no idea what you can do next, except to try looking and searching through previous questions and answers.

Comment: Well,I have found the reason why it would be like that,but no ideas to solve it.The card is plugged with a ISA collector.And way how the software get you the drivers is that it only provide the hardwares that are detected,but this kind of ISA collector seems doesn't work on the new standard Linux kernel driver libraries,so I have to find its driver from the old kernel.Ah,thank you anyway!